# how many blocks are made in Hadoop for the following example?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Assume my HDFS block size is 64 MB.

I have 4 files:

File A: 64MB * 3 + 2 MB;

File B: 62 MB;

There should be 4 blocks for File A each with 64 MB and one with 2 MB.

There should be one block for File B with 62 MB.

So in total there should be 6 blocks

Just because there is "free" space in the one of the blocks of File A which stores only 2 MB,
file B does NOT get appended to same block. Is it correct?

I have seen some tutorials where they say the "free" space in the block is utilized.

Comment: Which tutorials say this?

Comment: @climbage: one of them I recently encountered is here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQCNZoWLIVo (watch from 16.15 to 16.45)

Comment: @brainstorm can you check the numbers of the OP again and verify that there is no typo? I see two files (A and B) for File A I see 4 blocks (three of size 64 MB  and one of size 2MB). So in total 5 blocks, right?

Comment: @vefthym: what is the typo you are refering? I dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, there will be 6 blocks.  All this means is that a 2MB block only physically takes up 2MB on the datanode's hard disk and not a full block size which would be a waste of space.

Comment: yes, I understand that 2MB block physically takes up only 2MB on datanode's HD. but since there is "free" space in there of 62MB, will it use it?

Comment: Will what use it?  I'm not sure where the confusion is.  That free space is available for more blocks.

Comment: will the same block that has 2MB now will fit another 62MB?. I understand that at file system level there is no distinction.

Comment: Yes, it can "fit" another 62MB if you append more data to that file in the future

Comment: if I dont append to "that" file, but I have a new file of 62MB, it should be stored in a different block correct?

Comment: Correct.  A block will never span multiple files.

Comment: great. Thanks that clarified

Answer (score 1):

File A - 4 blocks. 3 with 64 & 1 with 2MB

File B - 1 block. 62 MB size.

if the replication is 3, there will be (4+1)*3=15 blocks in total.

What they mean in the video it seems is, the HDFS (DataNodes) will again utilize the space in the local file system since it is built on the top of local file system. If a block occupy less than 64MB , the remaining space in the file system is left un occupied. It can be used by some other blocks of some other files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you case here, the Block size is 64 MB,

Now you have 3 files with 64 MB each. For the information each block will have 150Kb of metadata information that is generated and is saved in the namenode. 
even if the block size is 1 MB or 50 MB or 64 MB the metadata information is the same

in your scenario  File A :   64 * 3  = 3 Blocks

2MB = 1 Block

Total for FileA = 3+1 = 4 Blocks.

File B = 62 MB = 1Block

Internally how it works :

What we assume is that if a file of 50 Mb is stored, we assume that the rest 14 Mb ( 64-50 =14 MB) goes wasted. but this is not how it works . you should understand that even if the file is > 64 MB the metadata information will be the same. The rest 14 Mb will be used by the other block whose metadata size also will be the same.